# Calculating infinite sum of binomial object, where probability is changing

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions, binomial-distribution

I would like to calculate the summation of an infinite series, where each term looks like a binomial object. However each binomial term has a different "probability" in the series.

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty{N \choose k}(f(x))^k(1-f(x))^{N-k}\\f(x)+(1-f(x))=1$$
where $f(x)$ is some arbitrary function on x.

If for instance, $f(x)=x^{-a}$. Is there a straightforward way to do this series summation? In the limit, the terms go to 0 so this series should converge. But I can't see a way to do the series summation.

I was thinking of trying a generating function approach. But I don't have much experience with manipulating them, so I am stuck there.

Comment: Should the sum be over $k$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @RobPratt No. This is precisely about what is different for this sum compared to the sum of a regular binomial distribution

Comment: So $N$ and $k$ are both fixed?

Comment: Correct. In this context they're both constants

Comment: I am assuming that $f(x) \in [0,1]$. In such a case if $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, then the sequence $f(1), f(2), \dots,$ considered as a partition of the interval $[0,1]$ and the sum can be approximated as a Riemann sum of the beta function.

Comment: Ah I see. thanks for that insight. What if I want to consider the case such as f(x) = x^{-a) so that f(x) is strictly decreasing? Is there a modification of this statement that works? I'm not too familiar with the beta function. @sudeep5221

Comment: I think the argument would work exactly the same way for a strictly decreasing function. It will still be a partition of the interval with the only difference that your indexing is reversed now.  You don't really need to know a lot about beta function. The integral that you are approximating through this Riemann sum just is a standard function and you can look it up on Wikipedia. Using the properties of the Riemann sum and the function $g(x) = x^k (1 - x)^{N-k}$ you can bound the error from the actual integral which would evaluate to $1/N$. Kindly let me know if this is not clear enough.

Comment: You can simply expand $\big(1-f(x)\big)^{N-k}$ using the binomial formula. For $f(x)=x^{-a}$, the result will be a linear combination of Riemann's $\zeta(an)$ for $k\leqslant n\leqslant N$. This should convince you that the *exact* evaluation is way out of reach for an *arbitrary* $f(x)$.

Comment: @metamorphy thanks. I think I see your point regarding arbitrary f(x). for the specific case of the inverse power law, I suppose you're saying even the linear combination is too messy?